# Django - Comments on multiple object types, which approach?

Tags: django, database-design, triggers, comments

An application has objects of multiple types (Articles, Songs, Profiles, etc), each having their own table. The desired functionality is to allow users to place comments on these objects. What is the best approach considering:

- Lookup latency (retrieving an object and all it's comments)
- Data integrity
- Maintainability

The options are:

- The Django contrib comments framework with signals fired on delete operation, calling a routine to delete comments from the comments table.
- The Django contrib comments framework with triggers in the database (a mapping between content type PK's / table names is needed).
- Give each object type a table for it's comments, with a foreign key.
- Give each object type a table for it's comments, AND use the Django comments framework. Drop the frameworks' comment table and create a view using UNION to retrieve all comments (including ON UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE triggers) from the comment tables, mimicing the behavior of the original comment framework table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use django.contrib.comments and django signals. You can always switch to a custom solution in the future, if you need it. Don't do premature optimizations, they are hard to maintain.